# Angular conditionally enabling/disabling HTML selects

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here's an image of what I am trying to do., Plunkr link below.

I have a numeric stepper and rows of select drop-downs. The number of drop-downs are bound (ng-model) to the numeric value of the stepper.

I have two array variables in $scope, that are used for ng-repeat with the individual drop-downs.

How do I writer event listeners such that? If I select a Non NONE value in Driver 1, Channel a1 should be disabled. And Channel a1 needs to be enabled if the Driver 1 is None.

Understand this could be done in jQuery, by writing a change handler and selecting the next sibling and disable it. How do i get the same in Angular ?

fyi. I am using $index variable to create distinct ids for each of the dropdowns
ex: driver_1, channel_1 etc

JSON Dump invokes a helper method in $scope, which prints out the JSON.

The code is on Plunkr. **http://plnkr.co/edit/j0ClqQ3P6LZtkgctFrRB**

---

[image]

---

**http://plnkr.co/edit/j0ClqQ3P6LZtkgctFrRB**

---

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ng-disabled`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) in the channel select:

`ng-disabled="value['selectedDriver'] != 'None'"`

Here is a demo: http://plnkr.co/UMP6XDe9bQa3y3dFHyE1

Comment: That worked! Thanks for the response. Is there a way to invoke a function on select change?

Comment: You can try ng-change.